# Pandas is returning empty dataframe from excel that has values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have and excel with 5 sheets. one main sheet that has values. The other 4 sheets are using formulas based on the first sheet. When I try to read excel using panadas for any of the 4 sheets. It returns empty dataframe.

**code:**

```
db_location = os.getcwd()+"\\Reports Database.xlsx"

df = pd.read_excel(db_location,sheet_name=company)
```

the excel name is correct and everything was working fine till yesterday. Suddenly it started to return empty dataframe. I use the excel only to read.

Comment: how about try to read without sheet name `df = pd.read_excel(db_location)` ?

Comment: Without the sheet name, it reads the first sheet which I don't need it.i need the other ones.

Answer (score 0):

When specifying the sheet name use quotation marks `sheet_name='Sheet1'`. Try this:

```
db_location = os.getcwd() + "\\Reports Database.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(db_location, sheet_name='company')
```

If `company` is a variable, make sure it is a string type and correct case (it is case sensitive)

```
company = 'Sheet1'    
db_location = os.getcwd() + "\\Reports Database.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(db_location, sheet_name=company)
```