# pandas read excel returns empty data

Tags: pandas, excel

Similar to [Pandas is returning empty dataframe from excel that has values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67698769/pandas-is-returning-empty-dataframe-from-excel-that-has-values)

I have a `xlsx` with multiple sheets. The sheet I am interested is not the first one.
I read the xlsx with:

```
df = pd.read_excel(path + input_file, sheet_name = 'sheet_name')
```

but when I read `df`, it is an empty data frame, with the correct column headers.

My solution where I was able to read it so data was present - not optimal

- open the xlsx, `save_as`, save again

As this is a task run out of hours, it is not possible to open and save a xlsx manually in order to process.

Is there another way that might work?

Comment: colleague saves it as `XLSX`

Comment: I am not seeing an issue with the code as you have it. I am thinking maybe that there is something  just slightly off that is not visually apparent like you are using the wrong sheet name... "Sheet_name" or "sheet-name" or "Sheet Name". Good luck!

Comment: I tested opening a file that was named test_file.XLSX. I was able to make the df and it had all the values.